# Looking to re-build an AngularJS App for a large display

Tags: angularjs, television, display

Can anyone give me some pointers on the most efficient way to rebuild an angularJS application that is built to run on TV sized monitors.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You need to explain more. Are you looking to change the look and feel of the application or just scale it up when the screen size gets really big.

Comment: It's actually a dashboard that a previous developer built, I'm looking to change the way it functions to where it works better on a large display such as TV's